# How do I prevent click event when I cancel drag in jquery UI?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

My intent is to have a series of folders and sub items (like a directory tree) and drag and drop the items to rearrange. When I simply click on a folder (a list item with a child ul) it should either slide open or slide close.

The problem is : I want to prevent the click event when I cancel a drag.

By cancel - I mean I start to drag the element, and then release the mouse without dropping it on top of any droppables.

My first guess was using `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` and `event.stopPropagation()`. This indeed prevents the click event when I cancel drags on list items that have no ul children.

However, when I cancel drag on li's that have ul children, the default click behavior occurs (which in this case is slideToggle).

How do I prevent the click event when I cancel drag of an li with ul children?

```
$("li").click(function (event) {
    console.log($(this).attr("class"));
    if ($(this).children("ul").length > 0) $(this).children("ul").slideToggle();
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
})

$("li").draggable({
    rever: false,
    helper: "clone",
    cursorAt: {
        top: -1,
        left: -1
    },
    stop: function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    }
});

$("span").droppable({
    hoverClass: "ui-state-active",
    greedy: true,
    tolerance: "pointer",
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        var dragged = ui.draggable
        var target = $(this).parent()

        if (target.children("ul").length == 1) {
            dragged.appendTo(target.children("ul"));
        } else {
            // depends upon whether I'm dragging from above or from below
            if (dragged.prev().is(target)) // dragging from below
            dragged.insertBefore(target)
            else dragged.insertAfter(target)
        }

        event.stopPropagation();
    },
});
```

Full code in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bh8tefxg/)

Comment: *"This indeed prevents the click event when I cancel drags on list items that have no ul children"* - this actually is not correct... [the click event still triggers](http://jsfiddle.net/bh8tefxg/6/) since you've binded the handler directly to the element... You think it's working since there is no action to take place..  And you've a typo in there: `rever` instead of `revert`... please update the question accordingly.. hope the answer helps.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to get around is to use separate elements to trigger both the actions.

For example, we use the [`handle`](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-handle) option.

> If specified, restricts dragging from starting unless the mousedown occurs on the specified element(s). Only elements that descend from the draggable element are permitted

To trigger the dragging, and a separate `<span>` element to trigger the toggle functionality.

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bh8tefxg/4/) (*Click the text for dragging and `+`/`-` for toggling*)

---

Another *hackish* work around is to keep track of a boolean flag -

We can set a `boolean` to `true` when dragging starts, and set it back to `false` after a **tiny timeout** inside the stop callback.

The click event will be triggered immediately when we release the mouse  - So if the click is triggered by a drag, the boolean flag will still be `true` since we'll only reset it after a short timeout. If it is a normal click - the flag will be false.

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bh8tefxg/5/)

---

```js
var dragging = false;
$("li").click(function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    $this = $(this);
    console.log(dragging);
    if (!dragging) {
        if ($this.children("ul").length > 0) $this.children("ul").slideToggle();
    }
});

$("li").draggable({
    revert: false,
    helper: "clone",
    cursorAt: {
        top: -1,
        left: -1
    },
    start: function (event) {
        dragging = true;
    },
    stop: function (event) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            dragging = false;
        }, 10);
    }
});

$("span").droppable({
    hoverClass: "ui-state-active",
    greedy: true,
    tolerance: "pointer",
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        var dragged = ui.draggable
        var target = $(this).parent()

        if (target.children("ul").length == 1) {
            dragged.appendTo(target.children("ul"));
        } else {
            // depends upon whether I'm dragging from above or from below
            if (dragged.prev().is(target)) // dragging from below
            dragged.insertBefore(target)
            else dragged.insertAfter(target)
        }

        event.stopPropagation();
    },
});
```

```css
.ui-state-active {
     background-color : red;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li><span>Test 1</span>

    </li>
    <li> <span>Test 2</span>

        <ul>
            <li class="A"><span>Test A</span>

            </li>
            <li class="B"><span>Test B</span>

            </li>
            <li class="C"><span>Test C</span>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><span>Test 3</span>

    </li>
    <li> <span>Test 4</span>

        <ul>
            <li><span>Test X</span>

            </li>
            <li><span>Test Y</span>

                <ul>
                    <li><span>F</span>

                    </li>
                    <li><span>G</span>

                    </li>
                    <li><span>H</span>

                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><span>Test Z</span>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```